# Total number of trustlines to an asset and total number of payments in a certain asset (Issuing Account)

Tags: accounts, assets, issuing

How can I get the total number of trustlines to a certain asset (Issuing account - asset)?
How can I get the total number of payments made in a special asset(Issuing account - asset)?

The number of trustlines can be retrieved from api.stellar.expert, however is there another way to get this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trustlines are part of the details provided by Horizon's [asset endpoint](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/resources/asset.html).

> num_accounts  number  The number of accounts that: 1) trust this asset and 2) where if the asset has the auth_required flag then the account is authorized to hold the asset.

The number of payments made with a given asset is a derived statistic that you'd need to calculate yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support, ire_and_curses. Yep, with
[link](https://horizon.stellar.org/assets?asset_code=<asset_code>&asset_issuer=<issuer_address>) I can get the number of trustlines.I am trying to find a way to get all payments in this asset.